# Display maximum index value from array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and I am stuck in one of my exercise: Iam supposed to display the maximum number of votes with the specific array index. How can I do it ?

import React, { useState } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'

```
const App = (props) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [points, setPoints] = useState([0,0,0,0,0,0]);
 
 
 const showRandom= () => {
    const change = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * anecdotes.length);
    setSelected(change)
  }

  const setVote=()=>{
    const copy = { ...points };// copy the last state 
    copy[selected] += 1; //increase by 1 on the selected points
    setPoints(copy); // setting in setpoints the clicked values
    console.log('after update',points)
    
  }

  
 

  return (
    <div>
      {props.anecdotes[selected]}<br/>
      has {points[selected]} votes <br/>
      <button onClick={showRandom}>next anecdotes</button>
      <button onClick={setVote}>Vote</button>
      <h2>Anectodes with most vote:</h2><br/>
      
    </div>
  )
}


const anecdotes = [
  'If it hurts, do it more often',
  'Adding manpower to a late software project makes it later!',
  'The first 90 percent of the code accounts for the first 90 percent of the development time...The remaining 10 percent of the code accounts for the other 90 percent of the development time.',
  'Any fool can write code that a computer can understand. Good programmers write code that humans can understand.',
  'Premature optimization is the root of all evil.',
  'Debugging is twice as hard as writing the code in the first place. Therefore, if you write the code as cleverly as possible, you are, by definition, not smart enough to debug it.'
]

ReactDOM.render(
  <App anecdotes={anecdotes} />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

const copy = { ...points } it's wrong 
it will be  const copy = [...points ]  
cause points is an array  
and use only anecdotes or props.anecdotes, not both

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
const App = ({anecdotes}) => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0)
  const [points, setPoints] = useState([0,0,0,0,0,0]);
 const showRandom= () => {
    const change = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * anecdotes.length);
    setSelected(change)
  }
  const setVote=()=>{
    const copy = [...points];// copy the last state 
    copy[selected] += 1; //increase by 1 on the selected points
    setPoints(copy); // setting in setpoints the clicked values

  }

  const renderMostVote = () => {
    const maxVote = Math.max(...points); // get the maximum point

    // at first all one will have 0 vote
    if (maxVote === 0) return null;

    // in case multiple Anectodes have same number of max vote
    const maxList = [];
    points.forEach((el, index) => {
      if ( el === maxVote ) maxList.push(index);
    });

    // if just one Anectodes can get max vote then it will be:
    // points.findIndex(el => el === maxVote)

    return maxList.map((el, index) => (
      <p key={index} > {anecdotes[el]} -- with {points[el]} vote </p>
    ))

  }

  return (
    <div>
      {anecdotes[selected]}<br/>
      has {points[selected]} votes <br/>
      <button onClick={showRandom}>next anecdotes</button>
      <button onClick={setVote}>Vote</button>
      <div>
       <h2> Anectodes with most vote: </h2>
       {renderMostVote()}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
export default App;
```

Comment: ok.. but how to get the maximum vote index and value..

Comment: do you mean maximum number of points state with index ?

Comment: Iam supposed to display the anectodes with most vote...

Comment: I've added rest line 
now you can get the anectodes with most vote

Comment: thank you for an answer, I tried in the following way, I couldn't display properly  function maxVote(){
    const max=Math.max(...points)
    console.log('the max value: ',max)
    const index=points.indexOf(max);
    return(props.anecdotes[index])

Comment: if you use const App = ({anecdotes}) => { } then it will be 
return(anecdotes[index]) . It's object destructuring
and If you use const App = props => { } then it will be 
return(props.anecdotes[index])